# Refactoring using Java 8

Tags: java, refactoring

I want to refactor my code by using Java 8, so I thought instead of using a setter method like this:

```
    Class MyService{
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(response.getName());
    user.setId(response.getId());
    user.setType(response.getType());
    user.setDesignation(response.getDesignation());
}
```

in  my Service Class.

I made a method in my User Pojo

```
Class User{

    public static User create(Response response){
    User user = new User();
    user.setName(response.getName());
    user.setId(response.getId());
    user.setType(response.getType());
    user.setDesignation(response.getDesignation());
    return user;
    }
}
```

and in my service class, I wrote:

```
List<User> userList=reponseList.stream().map(User::create).collect(toList());
```

Is it a right way or any better solution other than this? I actually have a lot of setter methods in my service.

Comment: Well, it doesn't compile, so it can't be a good way. If you get it to compile, and it's acceptable to have a coupling between User and Response (we have no idea what a Response is), then why not. That is called a factory method.

Comment: @JBNizet what do you mean by compile didnt get your point ?

Comment: @guri well "class" is all lowercase in Java, but you have "Class", so there's your first compile error.

Comment: ok i know but its just an example sorry for that :)

Comment: Your second error: create() must be static. Your third: user is not defined. Your fourth: the method doesn't return anything. Your fifth: semi-colons missing everywhere.

Comment: Its absolutely fine to set values for the instance variables in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a static create method, define a User constructor that takes a Response and initializes itself from that.

```
Class User{

    public User(Response response) {        
        setName(response.getName());
        setId(response.getId());
        setType(response.getType());
        setDesignation(response.getDesignation());
    }

}
```

Then you can call:

```
List<User> userList=responseList.stream().map(User::new).collect(toList());
```